# "AUTHENTICATE_"environment variables missing in Apache + LDAP authentication

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ldap, mod-wsgi, environment-variables

According to the [Apache 2.2 documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#exposed), after a successful authentication against Active Directory the LDAP attributes specified in the `AuthLDAPUrl` directive should be available as environment variables with the default prefix `AUTHENTICATE_`.

However, on a Debian 6.0.4 + Apache 2.2.16 + mod_wsgi the env vars are not set. I can authenticate without issues, and everything else is working fine.

Is there something I can do to have them set? A newer version of Apache and/or LDAP module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked in the WSGI environ dictionary passed to the WSGI application?

Any variables set using the SetEnv directive or internal equivalents in Apache, do not end up in os.environ of WSGI applications. Instead they end up in per request environ dictionary.